# Loop through a bunch of folderish content, which may be itself folderish?

Tags: python, recursion, plone

Suppose I have a content type, Folder, with 4 items.

```
+ MyObject
 - Child1
 - Child2
 - Child3
 + Child4
  - Child5
 - Child6
```

Suppose I have another content type (let's call it `Alias`). This `Alias` is mainly a reference to another object but folderish: it can contain a bunch of other aliases. I'm going to use `-->` to indicate this reference in the following tree representations.("Reference" is mainly an attribute called "reference" that receives the UID from the target object).

Suppose `MyAlias` now references my `MyObject`.

```
+ MyAlias --> MyObject
 - (Nothing)
```

When referencing to `MyObject`, `MyAlias` doesn't know that `MyObject` is a Folder, so the internal MyAlias children don't exist. I need to loop through everyone, and create, manually, an Alias inside `MyAlias`, that is a reference (having the same structure) to `MyObject` children. A little tree showing what should happen:

```
+ MyAlias --> MyObject
 - Alias --> Child1
 - Alias --> Child2
 - Alias --> Child3
 + Alias --> Child4
  - Alias --> Child5
 - Alias --> Child6
```

I would like to know the best way to iterate through `MyObject` items, and create the same structure with another objects, using some kind of loop and using `invokeFactory` in a subscriber. In the end, I would have BOTH trees existing: one of the actual Folder and children, and another of references to this same Folder and children.

(Summarizing: something like collective.alias, but in a really primitive form, just folders an documents, since I can't use collective.alias.)

Comment: Why not use the portal_catalog? It's your friend, it'll easily give you all the objects at your current path and deeper!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I have update my question with more information about the scenario.

Comment: @Somebody: I still see no reason not to use the catalog! :-)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Do I really need the catalog in this scenario? Since I already have an object direct reference, and have to loop through it's children, how using the catalog would help me?

Comment: @Somebody: the catalog gives you an instant list of all the children too; sort those results by path and you have a depth-first sorted list of the current context and all it's decendants. See @ggozad's answer below.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Hum, I need to "clone" a structure from a Folder, to the same structure but using "Alias" objects. I still don't know how am I going to do this loop using portal_catalog or a recursive generator. I think I have to study recursiveness a bit more :/

Comment: @Somebody: If you go that route, you can get the local children of a folderish object by calling `.contentIds()`. But if your alias object only needs the path or the UID of the original object, there is no need to load the whole tree into memory, the catalog gives you that information too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most elegant and Pythonic solution is to write a recursive generator. Assuming this is a method:

```
def iter_preorder(self):
    yield self
    # check for folderishness here if a non-folderish
    # node may have children as well
    for x in self.children:
        for y in x.iter_preorder():
            yield y
```

Then

```
for x in tree.iter_preorder():
    do_action(x)
```

This way, you don't actually have to wrap your action into a function/callable and there's no inversion of control.

Comment: This is not exactly Plone, but I've used this approach when already having the parent object I needed on a subscriber. `if target.isPrincipiaFolderish: for child in target.objectValues():`.

Answer (score 2):

Recursivity may help

```
def do_action(child):
    if child.isfolder():
        for i in child:
            do_action(i)
    else:
        child.setSomething()

do_action(MyObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not use the catalog? The catalog exists for solving these problems fast and securely for you, so that you can concentrate on things that matter. So, to find all the objects in some path:

```
ct = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
path = '/'.join(context.getPhysicalPath())
brains = ct.searchResults(path=path)
```

You can of course filter more in your query. Then,

```
for brain in brains:
    obj = brain.getObject()
    obj.setSomething()
```

The catalog is your friend, [read how to use it](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/indexing-and-searching/querying-the-catalog).

Comment: The real problem is about recursiveness. I can still use the catalog, but I need to loop all objects and all it's children. But instead of using @Martijn Pieters 's solution `.contentIds()`, I'm going to use `.objectValues()`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to do a content type migration. If that's the case, take a look at [Products.contentmigration](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/migrate-custom-types-with-products.contentmigration).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not migration, since both contents should exist. I need to have something similar to collective.alias, but I can't install it.